# Drag and Drop between Grid and "multiselect" control in EXTJS

Tags: extjs

Iam new to extjs , i need to do Drag and Drop functionality between Grid and "multiselect" control ..

i have configured to "store" with sample fields ,and set "enableDragDrop:true," for both the controls but i can't able to drag and drop between to controls..

Is there any other configuration need to be done ?..

Please provide any link showing drag and drop between 2 different controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder Multiselect List Box Example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/ReorderMultiSelectlistbox.htm

Multiple Tree D&D: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/two-trees.html

Multiple Grid D&D: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html

Grid Drag and Drop for Reordering Rows: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?21913-SOLVED-Grid-Drag-and-Drop-reorder-rows

I hope these help.