# Need solution for Multi Select in Extjs tree

Tags: extjs

Am complete stranger to Extjs. I have a requirement to allow multi select in the Extjs tree. Below piece of code is doing single select. i need to change the code to make it multi select with semi-colon between selected ids. Can anyone please change the code as per the requirement. Also if you could tell me to which field or variable the selected value of the tree is written into. Thanks in advance

```
    Ext.onReady(function() {   
Ext.QuickTips.init();
    var str='';
    var switch_flag = '';
    var approvals = '';
    var active_mode = '';

         var json = null;   
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'Dmscategorytree/ajax/Message',
            method: 'POST',
            params:{
                lifecycle_id: str,
                switch_flag: switch_flag,
                approvals: approvals,
                active_mode: active_mode
            },
            success: function(response, options) { 
            var path='';
            var id='';
            var text='';

            json=response.responseText;
            alert(json);
            json = json.replace(/&quot;/g,'\"');    
            json=Ext.util.JSON.decode(json);
            var flag=true;
            var myloader = new Ext.tree.TreeLoader();
            myloader.load = function(node, cb,scope) {
                        if(this.clearOnLoad){
                            while(node.firstChild){
                                node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
                            }
                        }
                        if(this.doPreload(node)){
                            this.runCallback(cb, scope || node, [node]);
                        }
                        cb();
            }

         var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
                animate:true, 
                autoScroll:true,
                //loader: new Tree.TreeLoader({dataUrl:'get-nodes.php'}),
                containerScroll: true,
                border: false,
                loader:myloader,
                 rootVisible: false,

                listeners:{
                    checkchange:function(node){
                        if(flag){
                            toggleCheck(tree.root,false,node.id);
                             path=node.attributes.value;
                             id=node.attributes.ID;
                             text=node.attributes.text;
                                path=path.replace(/\^/g,'/');   
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            function SelectToParent()
            {
            try
            {   
                parent.window.opener.callParent(path,id);
                parent.window.opener.focus();
                parent.window.close();
            } 
            catch(e){
                alert('got exception');
                window.close();
            }
            }

            function toggleCheck(node,isCheck,nodeId)
            {
                flag=false;
                if(node)
                {
                var args=[isCheck];
                node.cascade(function(){
                    c=args[0];
                    if(nodeId!=this.id){
                        this.ui.toggleCheck(c);
                        this.attributes.checked=c;
                    }
                    },null,args);
                }
                flag=true;
                return true;
            }
            var root = new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
                text: 'Ext JS',
                draggable:false, // disable root node dragging
                id:'src',
                children: json
            });
            tree.setRootNode(root);

            var topbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                region : 'north',
                height:30,
                margins: '0 0 0 5',
                items:[
                {
                    xtype: 'box',
                    id: 'title',
                    autoEl: {
                        html: '@label.chooseCat@'
                    }
                    ,width:525
                },
                {
                    text: '@label.Done@',
                    id: 'doneBtn',
                    tooltip: 'Done',
                    handler: SelectToParent
                }
                ]
            });
            topbar.render('tree');
            tree.render('tree');
            tree.getRootNode().expand();    
        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following links,

- [pass two id s in extjs 4 tree multiSelect and pass one id in single click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384565/pass-two-id-s-in-extjs-4-tree-multiselect-and-pass-one-id-in-single-click)
- [Multiselect Tree & Drag and Drop](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?28115-Multiselect-Tree-amp-Drag-and-Drop)
- [Drag and Drop between Grid and “multiselect” control in EXTJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127764/drag-and-drop-between-grid-and-multiselect-control-in-extjs)
- [Demo](http://www.users.on.net/~clear/ext/treetest.html)